# How to call a method using Input System in Unity, and pass a variable to it, or use a parent method that references a local variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I have a parent class (CharacterController) that contains several variables and several methods, and a child class (PlayerController) that has different values for those variables. I am using Input System to try to call one of CharacterController's methods inside of PlayerController, but I also want to be able to pass PlayerController's variable to it, or be able to reference the local PlayerController variable. CharacterController is purely a parent class, it is not used in the program. Is this possible? Below is a simplified version of the code.

Parent Class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    public MainManager mainManager { get; set; }
    public GameObject projectile;

    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        mainManager = GameObject.Find("Main Manager").GetComponent<MainManager>();
    }

    public virtual void FireProjectile(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
       if (context.performed)
        {
            Instantiate(projectile);
        }

    }
}
```

Child Class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : CharacterController
{
    PlayerControl playerControl;

    public GameObject projectile;

    void Start()
    {
        projectile = base.mainManager.projectiles[0];

        playerControl = new PlayerControl();
        
        
        playerControl.Player.Enable();
        playerControl.Player.Fire.performed += base.FireProjectile;

    }
```

MainManager is just a class that has a list of Game Objects labeled as projectiles in it. I have confirmed that it has the projectiles in it, and the variable projectile in PlayerController does show up as the correct game object in the main script. However, when I try to call FireProjectile I get "UnassignedReferenceException: The variable projectile of PlayerController has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the projectile variable of the PlayerController script in the inspector."

Is there a way to make FireProjectile see the PlayerController variable projectile? Or, is there a way to pass the projectile variable to FireProjectile, while using the Input System?

First I tried adding projectile as a parameter for FireProjectile and writing the line for calling FireProjectile as `playerControl.Player.Fire.performed += base.FireProjectile(projectile);`. When I did that, I got the errors "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action<UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext>'" and "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'tempProjectile' of 'CharacterController.FireProjectile(InputAction.CallbackContext, GameObject)'".

I tried to find any way to pass a parameter to a method called by Input System, but could not find a way.

Then I tried changing the "projectile" reference in FireProjectile to "this.projectile", but that didn't do anything either.

I then checked to see if projectile was null before and during the FireProjectile call, but it was the correct value before the call and null during.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't really see why this parent class exists ... what will other implementations look like and what o they really have in common? Main issue seems to be your field shaddowing by introducing `public GameObject projectile;` in both ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you are experiencing are due to some problems with the current code, please consider the following topics:

### 1 - Bad practice, can easily lead to confusion

Both `CharacterController` and `PlayerController` have a field with the same name:

`public GameObject projectile;`

Your future self could easily mistake which field belongs to which class, especially if you access it through the base one. As a general programming practice, **never declare variables with the same name on child classes.**

---

### 2 - UnassignedReferenceException

The field `PlayerController.projectile` is a serializable class, as a result, declaring it as public will make Unity automatically try to serialize it.
This error happened because you did not assign a reference to it in the inspector, since that variable is also declared in the base class (`CharacterController`) - it could be that Unity is only showing you the base one in the inspector, meaning the child one (`PlayerController.projectile`) does not have a reference.

This error is the same as NullReferenceException except Unity shows a different message since it is common for users to forget assigning a reference on the inspector.

---

### The solution to the first problem

You want to pass a unique `GameObject` as the projectile when using the `PlayerController` class, since `CharacterController.projectile` **is not** a static field, every different object of the type `CharacterController` may have different values for the `projectile` field.

Since `projectile` is serialized by Unity, you can manually assign which projectile you want on each `CharacterController` using the inspector (you may also do that via code just as you were on `PlayerController.Start()`, or you would be able to, if you did not declare a duplicate of that variable on the child class(`PlayerController`).

This means your problem can be solved by simply removing the duplicate on the child class, like this:

```
public class PlayerController : CharacterController
{
    PlayerControl playerControl;
    
    public GameObject projectile;
    
    void Start()
    {
        projectile = mainManager.projectiles[0];
    
        playerControl = new PlayerControl();
            
            
        playerControl.Player.Enable();
        playerControl.Player.Fire.performed += FireProjectile;    
    }
}
```

The issue was that you thought you were changing the value of `CharacterController.projectile` on `PlayerController.Start()`, when you were merely changing the value of `PlayerController.projectile` (which were two different things since you declared them separately)

Remember that the `CharacterController` class is not aware of any of it's children, so it can't access `PlayerController.projectile`.

By removing that duplicate from the child class, you ensure that you're changing the correct variable on `PlayerController.Start()`

---

### 3 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action<UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext>

`public event Action<InputAction.CallbackContext> performed`

Expects delegates that return void and require a single parameter of type `CallbackContext`, by adding a second parameter to `CharacterController.FireProjectile`, the compiler is no longer able to directly convert it to the required delegate.

As UnityEngine.InputSystem is a package maintained by Unity, I do not recommend changing it's source code before you are more knowledgeable on C#/Unity. However, you can easily solve this parameter problem using an anonymous method or lambda expression.

First, as you previously figured out, you need to add an additional parameter to `CharacterController.FireProjectile()`:

```
public virtual void FireProjectile(InputAction.CallbackContext context, GameObject projectileToFire)
{
   if (context.performed)
   {
       Instantiate(projectileToFire);
   }
}
```

Now, we will use a lambda expression that satisfies the required delegate of `InputAction.performed` while also providing the additional parameter want:

```
void Start()
{
    projectile = base.mainManager.projectiles[0];

    playerControl = new PlayerControl();
    playerControl.Player.Enable();
    playerControl.Player.Fire.performed += context => FireProjectile(context, projectile);
}
```

The lambda expression `context => FireProjectile(context, projectile);` is the equivalent of the following method:

```
private void FireDifferentProjectile(CallbackContext context)
{
    FireProjectile(context, projectile);
}
```

As such, the following is also valid:

```
    void Start()
    {
        projectile = base.mainManager.projectiles[0];
    
        playerControl = new PlayerControl();
        playerControl.Player.Enable();
        playerControl.Player.Fire.performed += FireDifferentProjectile;
    }

    private void FireDifferentProjectile(CallbackContext context)
    {
        FireProjectile(context, projectile);
    }
```

Keep in mind that this solution to the parameter problem is not required assuming you implemented the solution of the previous topic "**The solution to the first problem**".

---

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.6/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_performed
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Removing the projectile declaration fixed the problem. I had it in my head that just assigning projectile in PlayerController would change it for CharacterController and all its child classes, but I see why that's not the case.